# In C, is flushing the output buffer asynchronous (fflush)?

Tags: c, buffer

If not, can it be made asynchronous so other code can be executed without having to wait for the flushing to be completed?

Comment: No portable way to do this.  Not usually a problem.  Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @chqrlie: The C standard has threads.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: OK, no quick and simple way to do this.  Creating a thread for this seems overkill.

Comment: @chqrlie: One could create a thread that just loops waiting for a semaphore telling it to flush, so there is little overhead per flush.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I guess that would be a decent answer,  but this thread would lock the stream for the duration of the flush, effectively blocking other threads that attempt to write to the same stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard C function `fflush(stream)` causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file.  This occurs synchronously with respect to the current process, ie: `fflush()` does not return until the data has been delivered to the system, but the system may cache the file system so `fflush()` does not wait for the data to be written to the file system on disk or through the network.

There is no standard function to make this happen asynchronously.  You could conceivably use a separate thread to flush the stream buffer asynchronously, but fiddling with the same stream in different threads is not recommended.

Comment: so the difficulty is when 1 thread is flushing the buffer, other threads want to write to that same buffer?

Comment: @psquant: `fflush(stream) locks the stream for the duration of the flush, effectively blocking other threads that attempt to write to the same stream.